# Is it possible to build on this XSLT to convert to CSV formatted file?

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I am currently using xslt to transform my xml into xml on a format I can use.  I have a new requirement to deliver the transformed output xml in csv formatted file.

This is the xml before xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <bb:Report_Entry>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>
                <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </bb:Report_Entry>

</bb:Report_Data>
```

This is the XSLT used thanks to the help of @Tim C:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <bb:Report_Data>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="bb:Report_Data/bb:Report_Entry"/>
      </bb:Report_Data>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bb:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
         <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
      <xsl:param name="date"/>
      <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
         </bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId"/>
      </projectedBalanceTotal>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</bb:Report_Data>
```

I have an emergent requirement that needs each record in csv format such as:

```
projectedBalanceTotal.principalId, projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId, projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription, projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period, projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate, projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId
1040182074, Sick, Sick, 0, 08122012, 0260971
1040182074, Vacation, Vacation, 3.323077, 0260971
1040182074, Winter Recess, Winter Recess, 0, 0260971
```

etc etc

Can I just stack another template on top of this one to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure you can. XSLT is technology to convert from XML to any other **text** format.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk  Ok, I am only able to use one stylesheet in the system I'm using.  I've tried adding code that I've found onto my existing stylesheet but it's not working?  I need help altering my current stylesheet to convert to csv.

Comment: "Not working" is not going to get you much help, because it gives us very little information. If my answer below doesn't help, please tell us what code you added, what output it gives, and how that differs from what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to describe the fact that I"m not getting my desired result except the stylesheet I'm using is "not working."  The help I asked for was help altering my current stylesheet as I'm not sure how to do it.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: @LC_123: You wrote, "I've tried adding code that I've found onto my existing stylesheet but it's not working." Is it giving an error? What output is it giving? What code did you add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just stack another template on top of this one to accomplish
>   this?

Yes. But "how?" is a slightly trickier question.

If you can use XSLT 2.0, just take the output from your existing template, and treat it as the input document for another template that outputs CSV.

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, you'll need to use the nodeset() extension (non-standard but common in XSLT implementations). Use this function to convert the output from your existing template from a Result Tree Fragment (RTF) to a nodeset, so that it can be used by your new template that converts it to CSV.

### Update

OK, so change the XSLT version="1.0" to "2.0". Now change the output method from "xml" to "text".

Then modify the match="/" template to say:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="reportData">
      <bb:Report_Data>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="bb:Report_Data/bb:Report_Entry"/>
      </bb:Report_Data>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:text>projectedBalanceTotal.principalId, projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId, projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription, projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period, projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate, projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId</xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$reportData//projectedBalanceTotal" mode="xml2csv" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then add a template to transform a `<projectedBalanceTotal>` into a CSV record:

```
<xsl:template match="projectedBalanceTotal" mode="xml2csv">
   <xsl:value-of select="bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId" />
   <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
   ...
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> <!-- end of line -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem is that I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @LC_123: I can elaborate on either of the above. Can you use XSLT 2.0, or are you stuck with XSLT 1.0? If the latter, what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I can use XSLT 2.0. So my major problem is that I am a total noob to all of this and my workload at work has caused me to keep pushing XSLT training off time and time again.  

That being said,  my immediate problem is that I have no idea how to append my  XSLT to include code that will output my transformed XML in CSV format.  While I am completely open using XLST 2.0, I do not know how to achieve the results I've show above.  
What I've tried is literally copying and pasting code I've found online as a another template to my existing XSLT.  My results are an empty file.

Comment: @LarsH...I was able to get decent output using those two templates.  Thanks so much!  That was very helpful!!